# "This application cannot be installed because this installer has been mis-configured. Please contact the application author for assistance."

Tags: apache-flex, installation, air, certificate

I'm compile a .air file of my AIR application in FB4 and i'm getting that error when I try to install. I tried creating a new app, and just copying the code over and I get the same error. What am I doing wrong? I've even recreated the certificate multiple times.

Comment: Have you formally exported a release build to build the AIR Installer or just "compiled it"?  Maybe you should tell us the exact procedure you're following to export, or show us when a screenshot of the install.

Comment: Export release build -> follow wizard to create certificate with publisher name as my company name, then save the .air file to desktop with assets included.

Comment: maybe your certificate had expired?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was faced with the same problem..

Check out this post: http://wiki.showitfast.com/Misconfigured_Application

For me it did the trick - installed and ran the application without any problems.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this same problem and persued the above fix only I did not have "showit" on my machine. I did notice that since I had originally compiled my AIR app and had it on my desktop, my app was listed in the add/remove programs section. I removed from the list and "poof" my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's just because your certificate and the previous versions certificate didn't match.  In theory, uninstalling it would do the trick, but on my mac it didn't.

You can just change the name of your application in your app.xml and export another release.

Adobe is little obsequious on these things!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I am on a mac. I just went into my 'applications' folder and uninstalled the previous version of Adobe Installer I had in the system. ell dragged in into the trash and then it automatically uninstalled itself.

After that, re downloaded the app and it worked fine. 
Hope it works for you.